# Easy and fast software for mixing music

Tags: audio, mixing

Please suggest some good software that lets you mix music seamlessly.
I have tested some software and most of them are hard to use. I have tried fruity loops, FruityLoops I think is great for people who have some experience with mixing music. 
What I'm looking for is software for people who don't have experience with mixing.
The pieces of music I am planning to join are different from each other, they have different Tempo and Beat. The music will be used in my friend's dance and she wants the music to contentiously play without pausing or jumping to another song. She wants the songs to flow smoothly.

Any Advice?

Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you on?

Answer (score 5):

**[Mixxx](http://www.mixxx.org/)** is free, open source DJ software that gives you everything you need to perform live mixes.

[image]

Pretty easy to use, just load your tracks and record your mix.

*Available for Windows (x86 & x64, can be made portable, rip the installer with [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract)), Linux and Mac.*

Comment: the hardware mixers usually come with the software https://thedjplanet.com/5-best-dj-mixers-with-detailed-features-and-review/

Answer (score 2):

Try [Audacity](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/). It is very easy and intuitive to use. You can import multiple songs on separate tracks and smoothly fade from the end of one to the beginning of the other. Then you can output to a variety of audio formats including MP3 and AAC.

Comment: Audacity is certainly one of the finest sound editors, but not really the best mixer. p.s.: don't forget to install Lame MP3 encoder if you want to export to MP3.